# default string value

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

I want to set default value for a `varchar` column in sqlite.

default value is a path like `c:\log`

but sqliteStudio don't allow me to add this and after C value rest of values
are in purple:

`c:\log`

how should I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, string values must be quoted:

```
'c:\log'
```